# Unit tests failing when I use a custom view helper in the layout

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2

So I have created my custom view helper and used it in layout.phtml like this:

```
<?php echo $this->applicationBar(); ?>
```

It is working flawlessly in the browser but my unit tests that were working before are failing now:

```
1) UnitTests\Application\Controller\IndexControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for applicationBar
```

When I comment out the view helper in the layout file, test passes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, and i solved it in not a good way (but it solved for my specific problem).

The phpunit tests is not finding my factories view helpers, but it is finding my invokables. Then, i did the following:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'aplicationBar' => function($service) {
                $applicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
                return $applicationBar;
            },
        ),
        'invokables' => array(
            'applicationBar' => 'Application\View\Helper\ApplicationBar',
        ),
    );
```

When i use the browser, it uses the correct Factory. When i use phpunit, it uses the invokables.

The problem happens when i need to set some parameters. And then, i set some default parameters, that will be used only by phpunit.

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class ApplicationBar extends AbstractHelper {

    protected $parameter;

    public function __construct($parameter = 'something') {
        $this->parameter = $parameter;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        return $this->parameter;
    }

}
```

It is not the best solution, but if i solve it in a better way, i will post here.

Comment: Nice. Can you post it? I really didn't like my solution, and i came here for a better one.